# How to read bytes data coming from serial port in python?

Tags: python, serial-port, byte, pyserial

I'm writing on serial port with below configuration and try to read data from it. Actually I'm sending command to my hardware board which is connected to COM7 and hardware is also sending the data to that com port. Hence I want to read that data but I'm getting in HEx or bytes format. see below ..

**serial configuration:** 
'ComPort': '7', 'BaudRate': '115200', 'Parity': 'O', 'DataBit': '8', 'StopBit': '1', 'FlowCtrl': '0', 'DelayPerChar': '0', 'DelayPerLine': '0'

The Data that I'm receiving from hardware look like as below :
b'?G\xa1C!\xd2\x94\n\x82\xa2\xc1\xc9ee\xb3C\xe1'

and actual data which should be in readable format is like: $GB00402eef which I got from Tera term terminal.

let me know which encoding and decoding method will help me to get data in readable format..

Comment: Please include all relevant code and data in your post. See: [mcve].

Comment: Eight data bits and odd parity?!

Answer (score 0):

You have decode your string by using

```
varName.decode()
```

string method. UTF-8 is enough for your requirement.

Comment: Finally, I can read the data from receive buffer in a readable format as a string. The issue is with parity. Your computer program (sender) and Hardware(receiver) should be connected on the same parity. If they will have parity mismatched then you can get the data from receive buffer as garbage or in hex format.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can read the data from receive buffer in a readable format as a string.

**The issue is with parity configuration of a serial.**

Your computer program (sender) and Hardware(receiver) should be connected to the same parity. If they will have parity mismatched then you can get the data from receive buffer as garbage or in hex format.

For example: if the hardware is connected to Parity None then your serial configuration should also have parity 'None'. If you use parity 'odd' then it will have parity mismatched and data will not be received in proper format.